# What can I say about this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}q(x)\log\delta\left(x\right)~\textrm{d}x$?

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

I am computing the Kullback-Liebler distribution and run into the integral

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\delta\left(x\right)~\textrm{d}x.$

where $p(x)$ is a probability distribution, e.g., a Gaussian. and $\delta\left(x\right)$ the Dirac delta. Is there anything that I can assume?

Comment: hint: try replacing the delta by a limit that defines it and see if the integral converges to anything sensible and unique.

Comment: I'm not sure $\log \delta\left(x\right)$ is really a valid object, since $\log 0$ is undefined and that is the value that it would take almost everywhere.